# Accessing scope keys with string in HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display a list of buttons dynamically created and updated by the server through websocket.
My scope looks like this:

```
$scope = {
  buttons: ["buttonA", "buttonB"],
  buttonA: { caption: "OK" },
  buttonB: { caption: "Cancel" }
};
```

In my HTML, I will use a ng-repeat to go through the list of buttons, add them to the DOM and use the caption property of each button to use as the "value" attribute.

But I don't know how to access a json field from a string in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want a model like that. You can just maintain the buttons in $scope.buttons like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="b in buttons">
        <button>{{b.caption}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.buttons = [{ caption: "OK" }, { caption: "Cancel" }];
});
</script>
```

If there is some reason why you want the individual buttons on the "root" of the scope, you can use a lookup function like this:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="b in buttons">
        <button>{{lookup(b).caption}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MyCtrl",function ($scope) {
    $scope.buttons =  ["buttonA", "buttonB"];
    $scope.buttonA = { caption: "OK" };
    $scope.buttonB = { caption: "Cancel" };

    $scope.lookup = function(key) {
        return $scope[key];
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: So simple. I want it this way because the array represent the way button are displayed on the page (a grid of button represented as an array of array). On the other side, I don't want the function updating the attributes of the buttons to mess around with the array. A button might not be present in the array and I still want its state to be updated by the server.